# Cannot send dgram to external IP

Tags: c#, udp, client, ip

i need help :)

I have done tons o google search and found no answer, hopefully someone can help me here :)

So, i am writting simple P2P Video Chat client, that creates IP from textbox and connects to the "other" on port 5096. So, problem starts when i try to connect to external IP. Listener wont recieve packages, and i cannot transfer my image. Can someone please help me?

This is code of my UdpPictureSender:

```
class UDPPictureSender
    {
        bool closedSender = false;
        Socket sending_socket;
        IPAddress send_to_address;
        IPEndPoint sending_end_point;
        MemoryStream imageMemoryStream;


        public UDPPictureSender()
        { 
            initializeUdpPictureSender();

        }

        public void initializeUdpPictureSender()
        {
            sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse(ConnectionSettings.ipAdress);
            sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, 5096);
        }

        public void sendImage(Image image)
        {
            if (closedSender)
            {
                initializeUdpPictureSender();
            }

            imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(imageMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Byte[] bytes = imageMemoryStream.GetBuffer();
            sending_socket.SendTo(bytes, sending_end_point);
            imageMemoryStream.Flush();
        }

        public void closeConnection()
        {
            sending_socket.Close();
            send_to_address = null;
            sending_end_point = null;
            closedSender = true;
        }
    }
```

This is the code of UDPListener:

```
 class UDPListener
    {
        private const int listenPort = 5096;
        bool done = false;
        bool stoped = false; 

        UdpClient listener;
        IPEndPoint groupEP;
        Image received_data;
        byte [] receive_byte_array;
        MemoryStream currentMemoryStream;

        public UDPListener()
        {
            startupSettings();
        } 

        public  void startupSettings() 
        {
            groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
            listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        }
        public Image listenForImages()
        {
            if (stoped)
            {
                startupSettings();
                stoped = false;
            }
            try
            {
                while (!done)
                {

                    receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                    currentMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(receive_byte_array);
                    received_data = Image.FromStream(currentMemoryStream);
                    return received_data;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            listener.Close();
            return null;
        }

        public void closeConnection()
        {
            listener.Close();
            stoped = true;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

That exception is being thrown from `IPAddress.Parse` because `ConnectionSettings.ipAdress` is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.

What ever you are using isn't a valid IP address.  Perhaps you have an embeded space or something like that.

Comment: i checked that, used trim(), and still nothing.

Comment: @hrza what is hard to understand? you pass an invalid address (possible) to IPAddress.Parse. `An invalid IP address was specified.` Check your code and see what is passed.

Comment: can you give me an example of string that i should parse?

Comment: i edited post and add a UDPListener, if someone could check if I am doing something wrong, i will be very thankful :)))

Comment: @hrza you're code for your UDPListener doesn't matter - you are passing an invalid IP address to `IPAddress.Parse`.  It should just be any IP address like "173.194.73.106" (www.google.com)

Comment: Ok, i solved it. Now its stuck on udp listener and cannot recieve anything, so my question changes to: how to send images via UDP :), and to recieve them? I know udp doesnt have error checking, and if packet loss accure, i cannot "recieve image", but can i somehow manipulate with it?

Answer (score 0):

In your data sending code, try sending the data a few times. It is not necessary that on the very first instance you will receive the data at the receivers end. Its UDP and not TCP, so delivery is rarely ensured unless you have something of mechanism to ensure delivery. Make sure you have a fixed buffer size and try sending the image in chunks instead of a whole.